# Some endpoints in Spring Boot app not working when receiving request from Angular front end

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have the following end point:

```
@PutMapping(path = "/like/{id}")
public void likeQuestion(@PathVariable("id") String id, @Valid @NotNull @RequestBody Student student) {
    logger.info(id, student);
    questionService.likeQuestion(id, student);
}
```

This does not work when I try to send the request from the Angular front end:

```
likeQuestion(id: string, student: Student) {
  console.log(id, student);
return this.http.put(
  environment.baseUrl + '/api/questions/like/' + id,
  student
);

}
```

the console still logs out the `id` and `student`, however, the endpoint does not get logged.

I have another endpoint in the same file that works:

```
 @PutMapping(path = "/edit-comment/{id}")
public void editComment(@PathVariable("id") String id, @Valid @NotNull @RequestBody Comment comment) {
    logger.info("Editing comment");
    questionService.editComment(id, comment);
}
```

What could be the potential problem here? Thank you. The request mapping for the controller is `@RequestMapping("api/questions")`, which matches the frontend request uri, so I don't know what could be the problem.

I tried checking the network tab in the dev tool but could not find any request being made...

Comment: what is http status code that receive ?

Comment: It doesn't even show in the dev tool, how can I check for that?

Comment: What is the error in backend..?

Comment: I could not even see it, the frontend does not make a call to the endpoint...

Answer (score 5):

maybe Student DTO field's is not valid, and @valid or @notNull fire before controller's log

Answer (score 1):

It's my bad everyone, I'm sorry. I forgot to subscribe after calling http.